# Clojure : how can I remove an object from memory?

Tags: clojure

I just finish a program which basically collects data and computes several tables (which differ generally by filters or aggregation level (I wrote a SELECT + GROUP BY like Clojure function) that I finally use to compute a summary table. This summary table is used later and is only 30 000 lines long.

To make you understand, this is the command I have to launch :

```
(def summary-pages (merge-summary-pages (merge-pages-stock (compute-stock) (compute-pages) (compute-xx-prices) (compute-g) (compute-brands) (compute-prices) (compute-sales) (compute-sales-month))
                                        (merge-full-pages-per-page (merge-full-pages (merge-pages-stock (compute-stock) (compute-pages) (compute-xx-prices) (compute-g) (compute-brands) (compute-prices) (compute-sales) (compute-sales-month)) (merge-pages-stock-excluded (compute-pages) (compute-stock) (compute-g) (compute-brands) (compute-prices) (compute-sales) (compute-sales-month))))
                                        (merge-pages-stock-per-page (merge-pages-stock (compute-stock) (compute-pages) (compute-xx-prices) (compute-g) (compute-brands) (compute-prices) (compute-sales) (compute-sales-month)))
                                        (merge-affectations-count (compute-affectations))))
```

As you can see, I call the same data several time (and in fact `(compute-pages)` calls `compute-affectations`.

This works but the problem is that `compute-pages` and especially `compute-affectations` are quite huge queries on google BQ (15 millions lines) and microsoft sql server (45 millions lines).

The problem is that it takes time to query them 4-5 times and I'm also afraid to break the database.
Another problem is that I must compute all `compute-affectations` because it comes from sql server and my left-join use group-by.

I tried to split the job with `def` but I have GC overhead error.
Because I can clean `affectations` after some computation, I tried

```
(def affectations nil)
```

...does not change anything, I do not see memory free in microsoft command panel.

Is there a way to clean memory ?

In Python my program works without problem at all (in fact memory usage is at most 80%) but here with a heap space of 13gb I always have problems when I use def for any sub-data.
I have 16gb ram so I cannot increase the heap space, plus I find it strange that such "small" data takes so much memory.

I computed test data with csv and the base data is only 3.3gb...

**EDIT**

Working code (part of it) :

```
            (let [_ (init-config! path)
                 _ (write-affectations)
                 _ (write-pages)
                 _ (spit "prepared-pages.edn" (prn-str (prepare-pages (read-pages))) :append :true)
                 _ (write-stock)
                 _ (write-prices)
                 _ (write-xx-prices)
                 _ (write-brands)
                 _ (write-g)
                 _ (write-vehicles)
                 _ (write-sales)
                 _ (write-sales-month)
                 _ (System/gc)
                stock (read-stock)
                affectations (read-affectations)
                pages (read-pages)
                prepared-pages (prepare-pages pages)
                xx-prices (read-xx-prices)
                g (read-g)
                brands (read-brands)
                prices (read-prices)
                sales (read-sales)
                sales-month (read-sales-month)
                pages-stock (merge-pages-stock stock prepared-pages xx-prices g brands prices sales sales-month)
                pages-stock-excluded (merge-pages-stock-excluded prepared-pages stock g brands prices sales sales-month)
                full-pages-per-page (-> (merge-full-pages pages-stock pages-stock-excluded)
                                        (merge-full-pages-per-page))
                pages-stock-per-page (merge-pages-stock-per-page pages-stock)
                affectations-count (merge-affectations-count affectations)
                summary-pages (doall (merge-summary-pages pages-stock full-pages-per-page pages-stock-per-page affectations-count))
                _ (System/gc)
                _ (io/delete-file "affectations.edn")
                _ (io/delete-file "pages.edn")
                _ (io/delete-file "prepared-pages.edn")
                _ (io/delete-file "stock.edn")
                _ (io/delete-file "prices.edn")
                _ (io/delete-file "xx-prices.edn")
                _ (io/delete-file "brands.edn")
                _ (io/delete-file "g.edn")
                _ (io/delete-file "vehicles.edn")
                _ (io/delete-file "sales.edn")
                _ (io/delete-file "sales-month.edn")
```

I write the content of queries on HDD (.edn files), then I read it lazily and pass it to function.

Thanks !

Comment: If all those calls to `compute-pages` or `compute-affectations` are returning the same data every time, why don't you use `let`?

Comment: Hello, thanks I tried it too but in fact all my data are on a big let because i'm on the -main part. In fact even the command I described does not work with sql server and BQ. I found a dumb tweak but which is working : first query these two specific tables, write it immediately on HDD (CSV) by chunks, then pass it to the (compute-summary-pages). Since I'm not at all an expert programmer, I have no real clue on what happening : maybe string data consumes too much memory (BQ) and/or SQL query is not lazy ??

Comment: BTW, this is a class of problem that a good memory profiler will be invaluable in solving. It costs money (unless you're using it exclusively for OSS work and request a free license), but YourKit does an excellent job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing exactly what these do it's hard to check for situations like:

- holding onto the head of a huge lazy sequence
- lazy bugs (code closes a DB connection before reading a lazy sequence of results)
- holding too many copies of the same thing in memory.

This last one is clearly part of (or perhaps all of) your problem. I de-duplicated your example so each value is only computed once.

```
(def summary-pages
  (let [stock (compute-stock)
        pages (compute-pages)
        prices (compute-prices)
        brands (compute-brands)
        sales-month (compute-sales-month)
        g (compute-g)
        sales (compute-sales)
        xx-prices (compute-xx-prices)
        pages-stock (merge-pages-stock stock pages xx-prices g brands prices sales sales-month)
        pages-stock-excluded (merge-pages-stock-excluded pages stock g brands prices sales sales-month)
        full-pages-per-page (merge-full-pages-per-page (merge-full-pages pages-stock pages-stock-excluded))
        pages-stock-per-page (merge-pages-stock-per-page pages-stock)
        affectations-count (merge-affectations-count (compute-affectations))]
       (merge-summary-pages pages-stock 
                            full-pages-per-page
                            pages-stock-per-page
                            affectations-count)))
```

your next step is to comment out all but the first one, verify that it runs correctly and in a reasonable amount of time. Then uncomment the next and repeat.

---

since your data is large and you would like your code to use lazy sequences to work on a window of it at a time, I'd like to introduce you to how "local binding" and "locals clearing" work in Clojure.

here is an example of a sequence that "should" cause an out of memory exception by holding the head of a sequence of a billion Integers:

```
user> (time
       (let [huge-sequence (range 1e9)]
         (last huge-sequence)))
"Elapsed time: 49406.048091 msecs"
999999999
```

but it does not? why?

It must have somehow figured out that it does not actually need to store the head of the huge-sequence because nobody will be using it after! So let's test this by changing the example to it must hold the head and see if it still works

```
user> (time
       (let [huge-sequence (range 1e9)]
         (last huge-sequence)
         (first huge-sequence)))
```

This time my CPU fan kicks in and all 8 processors spin up to 100% immediately. After five minutes I'm starting to get impatient, so I'll head out to lunch and see if it finishes while I'm eating. So far our hypothesis is looking accurate.

So when you define a bunch of sequences in a big `let` block and then make a single function call that uses them a bunch of times and never touches them after that call, the heads of the sequence can usually be cleared at function call time and it will "magically" just work. This is why I suggested that you test these one at a time from top to bottom.

There is **almost** never a reason in Clojure to define the same data twice, we take referential transparency seriously around here.

---

update: the test eventually ran out of memory, though the time call was bypassed by the thrown exception so I don't know how long it actually took:

```
user> (time
       (let [huge-sequence (range 1e9)]
         (last huge-sequence)
         (first huge-sequence)))
OutOfMemoryError Java heap space  [trace missing]
```

Comment: I will try too but if I understand well how it works, when I bind a lazy-reader  in a let, if I compute all teh sequence once, it will stay in memory. When I do this big computation (my code), once a super-data is compute (let's say full-pages-per-pages), i see a big drop in memory because intermediate data is cleaned. That is why it works vs binding all. I have almost the good amount of memory because when I close all my applications, I have no real memory problems. I also wrote all in edn so that I access data lazily without donwload times.

Comment: Your comment touches on a lot, so I'll add the fundamentals to the answer and we can touch on specifics later if you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried your solution and it's working too. It may be better because it seem that computation time have been faster but I'm still at max memory at some point. Not a problem if it works and code is better now. I think the real problematic thing was the MS SQL query, writing it to the HDD allows me to read it with line-seq lazily. I have the impression that Clojure keep in memory last objects even if they are not bound, still the memory clean occured so all fine ! I edited my answer with sample code

Comment: Thanks for adding the finished answer to others can learn from this later.